# How to sort Terraform upgrade issues for state locks?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am using the terraform Version

```
Terraform v0.13.0
```

#### Expected Behavior Of The Process

It should have destroyed my resources but it threw an error then I tried to upgrade and It should have shown me the update for version of `v0.15.3` but the reverse is the case

#### Error Behavior

```
Error: Error locking state: Error acquiring the state lock: state snapshot was created by Terraform v0.15.3, which is newer than current v0.13.0; upgrade to Terraform v0.15.3 or greater to work with this state

Terraform acquires a state lock to protect the state from being written
by multiple users at the same time. Please resolve the issue above and try
again. For most commands, you can disable locking with the "-lock=false"
flag, but this is not recommended.
```

Then when I try to upgrade, it goes through but the version still shows as displayed below:

```
Your version of Terraform is out of date! The latest version is 0.15.4. You can update by downloading from https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html
Terraform v0.13.0
```

#### Steps to Reproduce

Please list the full steps required to reproduce the issue, for example:

1. git clone this [repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/boundary-reference-architecture)
2. `terraform init`
3. `terraform apply`
4. `terraform destroy`
5. `terraform --version`
6. `sudo apt install terraform=0.15.3`
7. `terraform --version`

The terraform has refused to upgrade so the destroy command could work. But if you think, I could do anything to circumvent this error, please share!

Answer (score 0):

I don't work much with Linux based systems but most likely your PATH is pointing to the old version of Terraform. Check this [link](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/install-cli) on the `Install Terraform` section at the left hand side.

If you run `terraform --version` I'm assuming you get the older version?

You could try to see if the `-lock=false` flag works in your `init` and `destroy` steps, but I don't have much experience with using that flag.

As a last alternative you could go into your cloud provider and manually delete the state file from your storage bucket and manually delete all provisioned resources if needed and start from a fresh slate.

Comment: Okay let me try that. In the meantime, would you mind checking out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674617/how-to-solve-terraform-error-upload-failed-wait-remote-command-exited-without

Answer (score 0):

Consider using TF switch, which allows you to switch between multiple versions of terraform.

> The tfswitch command line tool lets you switch between different versions of terraform. If you do not have a particular version of terraform installed, tfswitch lets you download the version you desire. The installation is minimal and easy. Once installed, simply select the version you require from the dropdown and start using terraform

With this tool you can regain control of the state file under the correct version of terraform, and then switch between any version you need to use.

See https://tfswitch.warrensbox.com/

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I have installed tfswitch and switched the version of terraform but when I try ```terraform -version```, it shows me the old version still

Comment: Well you need to swtich to the new version. Try `tfswitch v0.13.0` and confirm that version. Then try  `tfswitch v0.15.3`

Comment: Okay let me try that. In the meantime, would you mind checking out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67674617/how-to-solve-terraform-error-upload-failed-wait-remote-command-exited-without